# Would a Quora question on a mobile device fall under web applications or Android/iPhone discussions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm having an issue responding to questions on Quora.com through my iPhone and Android device. Would a question of that nature fall under web applications, Android, iPhone or somewhere else?

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/92540/website-recommendations?

Comment: Why not ask... on quora?  Or do you just ask questions about SE over there?  Seriously, my mind is boggling right now.  You have boggled me.

Comment: Honestly, I feel a question like the one I asked would get a more thought out answer on SE. Quora's nice but it's no SE.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Web Applications is the most relevant SE site. There is [quora](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quora) tag, and there are questions such as: [Is there a way to visit Quora in mobile URL when I'm on desktop?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/92214)

But if you think it's a bug with the site, then you should contact Quora support directly.

Android site is for issues specific to Android, which yours isn't (since it also occurs on iPhone). Similar for Apple.